# iphone maps app message bar below UINavigationController bar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, mapkit

I am trying to add the message bar that shows up in the maps app, like the one that says "53 m" in the screenshot below.  anyone know how to do this?  I'm guessing it's part of the navigationController?  Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is add a `UIView` to the viewController that contains the mapView. Be sure it is positioned over the `MKMapView`. Also you can set the `alpha` property of the new view to make it look like the screenshot.

Add a `UILabel` as a subview of the new view and link it as a `IBOulet` so you can set the text.